# how to customize facebook share button with <div> element of page

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I am having facebook share button. I am trying to display specific content of my page( element) to share on facebook.

```
<a title="Share this article/post/whatever on Facebook" 
 href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?
 u=the url you want to share
 &t=title of the article/post/whatever" 
 target="_blank">
 <img src="your/path/to/facebook-icon.png" 
         alt="Share on Facebook" />
```

I want to share content of my  tag from web page to facebook wall.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking. Do you need to to share the current URL of the page? What kind of backend system are you using? Something like Wordpress?

Comment: I want to add content of <div> Text of Div Tag </div>  tag from web page to face book wall as share how can i achive this?